# providing a default argument to a function, but that argument is a struct

Tags: c++, function

```
struct mat4x4
{
    float m[4][4] = {0};
};
```

Basically, I have function to multiply a 4x4 matrix.

```
mat4x4 matrix_matrix(mat4x4 m1, mat4x4 m2)
{
    mat4x4 product.m[someValue][someValue] = do_calculations_and_get_product();
    return product;
}
```

So what I was thinking is to take a third `mat4x4` as argument by reference, save the product in that new matrix and return that matrix. But that means a third argument must be passed while calling it. I want to be able to call it by passing only 2 matrices and expect a product matrix as an output AND if third matrix is given, I want it to save the results to that third matrix and also return that matrix.
From reading some of the other posts I came up with this

```
mat4x4 matrix_matrix(mat4x4 m1, mat4x4 m2, const mat4x4 & m3 = mat4x4{})
{
    m3.m[somevalue][somevalue] = do_calculations_and_get_product();
    return m3;
}
```

but I am getting an error: `expression must be a modifiable lvalue`, with a red wiggly line under `m3`. I don't really know what I am doing and need someone to help me. Thanks

Removing const gives the following error:

```
initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
```

with a red wiggly line under `mat4x4`{} in function defination.

Comment: Well, the first line of your function is modifying `m3`, but you declared it as `const`. This has nothing to do with a struct argument. The function `void f(const int &a = 42) { a = 5; }` would give you the same error.

Comment: I get a different error is if I don't declare it as const

Comment: Then add that information, i.e. the modified code, and the corresponding error, to the question.

Comment: How about using overloads instead?

Comment: Why not take the default argument by non-const l-value, i.e. `mat4x4 m3 = mat4x4{}`

Comment: @cigin but doesn't not having `&` mean that m3 would be local to the function ?

Comment: @eerorika The different post i read did suggest using overloads too, but the example was unclear and i didn't really understand what to do.

Comment: Aah, I see, you want to modify the 3rd argument. I misunderstood that.

Comment: Your problem lies in scope. When your function executes it gets space reserved for all the code between the brackets. Any variables created would only exist in that scope. Also arrays and matricies are represented as pointers, which point to data areas within the scope. The second the code within the scope exits that scope and all its variables are removed. Therefore you can't create a matrix within the function and return it because it is not just a value but a bunch of pointers pointing to data areas that don't exist anymore. Bite the bullet and use three variables.

Comment: @SteveMucci _"you can't create a matrix within the function and return it"_ That's wrong. You can as you can see in the answers.

Comment: maybe consider using operator overloading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a compiler supporting C++17 this becomes a simple matter of using `std::optional` with `std::reference_wrapper`. Implicit conversions do all the hard work for you.

```
#include <optional>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

struct mat4x4
{
    float m[4][4] = {0};
};

mat4x4 matrix_matrix(mat4x4 m1, mat4x4 m2,
             std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<mat4x4>
             > m3=std::nullopt)
{
    mat4x4 new_m;

    // Calculate something in new_m;

    if (m3)
        *m3=new_m;

    return new_m;
}

void test()
{
    mat4x4 m1, m2, m3, mret;

    mret=matrix_matrix(m1, m2);

    mret=matrix_matrix(m1, m2, m3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use overloads:

```
struct mat4x4
{
    float m[4][4] = {0};
};

// Overload without reference
mat4x4 matrix_matrix(mat4x4, mat4x4)
{
    mat4x4 m3;
    m3.m[somevalue][somevalue] = do_calculations_and_get_product();
    return m3;
}

// Overload with reference
mat4x4 matrix_matrix(mat4x4, mat4x4, mat4x4 &m3)
// or do you want to return a reference?
// mat4x4 &matrix_matrix(mat4x4, mat4x4, mat4x4 &m3)
{
    m3.m[somevalue][somevalue] = do_calculations_and_get_product();
    return m3;
}
```